# Responsive menu with adaptive positioning

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Ok, so bear with me here, I've been a backend developer for quite a while, and while I've taken a few frontend and ux courses throughout my career on html/css I'm still wondering where can I find certain instruction or article as to where can I achieve a menu that is not only responsive (This is actually not at all complicated) but also adapts its position when the viewport's position changes.

My goal is to make a menu similar to this one: https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/ which as soon as you start scrolling down, the viewport position changes and the menu changes its position to the top, becomes smaller and even the logo changes.

If anyone has any article or place where I can read a little more on how to achieve this, I would be grateful.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, **tutorial**, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They call it Sticky Menu.
You need html/css and Javascript to achieve this effect.

[here is a link to an example.](https://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD)

Basically when you scroll to a certain amount, you add a class of fixed, than that fixed class has some styles like `position: fixed; top: 0;` etc